# How can I add a row vector to a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

**1. First**

I have the following data frame

```
weight <- c(74,85,58,80)    
height <- c(1.68,1.83,1.58,1.72)
age <- c(22,25,21,20)
names <- c("Peter","Joseph","Marie","Xavier")
sex <- c("Male","Male","Woman","Woman")
data <- data.frame(weight,height,age,names,sex)
```

I need to add a new individual to the data frame: name= "Anne", weight= 70, height= 1.72 sex= Woman. I set those values as a vector:

```
Anne <- c(70,1.72,24,"Anne","Woman")
```

I used rbind to add the vector Anne

```
data <- rbind(data,Anne)
```

But I got this warning.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[`<-.factor``(*tmp*, ri, value = "Ana") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[`<-.factor``(*tmp*, ri, value = "Mujer") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

"Anne" and "Woman" appear  as NA in the data frame. How can I fix this?

**2. Second**

Also, how can I add a column to the data dataframe, named HEIGHT. Where, if the individual measures more than 1.78, he will have the value "High"; otherwise it will have the value "Normal".

**APPRECIATE YOUR HELP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt would work if you read the data as characters as shown at the end of this post.

Alternatively, you can also do

```
data[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- Anne
data$HEIGHT <- ifelse(data$height > 1.78, "High", "Normal")
#Faster way would be
#data$HEIGHT <- c("Normal", "High")[(data$height > 1.78) + 1]

data
#  weight height age  names   sex HEIGHT
#1     74   1.68  22  Peter  Male Normal
#2     85   1.83  25 Joseph  Male   High
#3     58   1.58  21  Marie Woman Normal
#4     80   1.72  20 Xavier Woman Normal
#5     70   1.72  24   Anne Woman Normal
```

**data**

Read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
data <- data.frame(weight,height,age,names,sex, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```